# How can I remove extra whitespace from the bottom of a line chart in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

As you can see below with the canvas element highlighted, there is considerable whitespace below the x axis label.  If I resize the canvas, the whitespace stays proportional to the height of it.  Are there any settings that control this whitespace?  I've ruled out padding and do not see any settings for margins.

Thanks!

[image: Line chart with extra whitespace below x axis]

Here is the JavaScript that renders the chart:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: true
        },
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: true,
          maxTicksLimit: 1
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          drawBorder: false
        },
        ticks: {
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return '$' + addCommas(value);
          }
        }
      }]
    },
    layout: {
      padding: 5
    }
  },
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
      { 
        data: values,
        fill: false,
        borderColor: "blue"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

And the complete jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/rsn288fh/2/

Comment: Please add code of your chart to the question, and tell us what you have tried so far. My first thought is that it could be space reserved for legend items.

Comment: A JSFiddle reproducing the problem would be extremely helpful as well.

Comment: Oops, posted early AM and should have known better.  So far I've only tried adjusting the padding as outlined in http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html?h=padding.  I've added the code as well as a fiddle.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know you said you ruled out padding, but this is the only option I can see working:

```
options: {
    layout: {
        padding: {
            bottom: -20
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you can play with the `-20` to what works for you.

Here is the [reference for padding](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html) for chartjs, if you wanted to see more

#### EDIT:

I've updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rsn288fh/4/), with a colored div below the chart.  As you resize it seems to stay at the same spot below the chart.

Comment: Ah, never thought to use negative padding.  This is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Changing the `tickMarkLength` to 0 results in no padding on the left or bottom of the chart (or wherever your axis happens to be).

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration

> tickMarkLength
>
> Length in pixels that the grid lines will draw into the axis area.

```
const options = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          display: false,
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          tickMarkLength: 0,
        },
      },
    ],
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          display: false,
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          tickMarkLength: 0,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: This was such an easy plug and play solution